# How to print the command inside 'if'?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

```
if  g++ test.cpp > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    ./a.out
else
    g++ test.cpp
fi
```

I was writing a shell script to run if gcc returns no errors or else print the errors. How can I print the errors without compiling the code second time?

Comment: Note that bash has the `&> file` redirection which sends both stdout and stderr to the file

Comment: Do you want see _only_ error messages, the "normal" compiler messages not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing would be:

```
if g++ test.cpp > /tmp/some_temp_file 2>&1
then
    ./a.out
else
    cat /tmp/some_temp_file
fi
rm /tmp/some_temp_file
```

Answer (score 2):

If by printing errors you mean only the output of stderr, then you can just do

```
g++ test.cpp >/dev/null && ./a.out
```

But, more generally, redirecting output to a file, as in depesz' answer, is the simplest method that also affords you the power of manipulating that output as you see fit for your own purposes. Any other trickery may have portability issues, but bear in mind that redirection may fail for its own reasons (file not writable, no more space left on the disk etc.).